# Prism EventAggregator. Receive the event and send it again

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, eventaggregator

In my project I have three ViewModels (for example, `ViewModelA`, `ViewModelB` and `ViewModelC`).
I need to write the following logic.
The `ViewModelA` sends the value to `ViewModelB` using the `EventAggregator` from Prism.
The `ViewModelB` receives the value and sends it to `ViewModelC`.
The `ViewModelC` receives the value and doing something.

Here is the code:

```
// The data that will be send using the event aggregator.
class EventData : PubSubEvent<int>
{ 
}

class ViewModelA
{
    IEventAggregator m_eventAggregator;

    public ViewModelA(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        m_eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        // Publish some value.
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<EventData>().Publish(10);
    }
}

class ViewModelB
{
    IEventAggregator m_eventAggregator;

    public ViewModelB(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        m_eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        eventAggregator.GetEvent<EventData>().Subscribe(OnDataReceived);
    }

    void OnDataReceived(int value)
    {
        // Here I want to send the value to the ViewModelC. How can I do it?
    }
}
```

PS: it is the part of the big project. So, please don’t suggest sending from `ViewModelA` to `ViewModelC` directly, without the `ViewModelB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event aggregator works in a way that everybody can listen to every event. So, if you want to send from A to B (and then from B to C), you need two distinct "private" events.

A:

```
 eventAggregator.Publish<AtoB>( value );
```

B:

```
 eventAggregator.Subscribe<AtoB>( x => {
                                           var y = process(x);
                                           eventAggregator.Publish<BtoC>( y );
                                       } );
```

C:

```
 eventAggregator.Subscribe<BtoC>( x => whatever( x ) );
```

Side-note: what you publish and subscribe is *the event type*, not the payload type. The naming of your event (`EventData`) is a bit awkward, because one will confuse it with the payload. A better name would be `DataEvent`... or, here, `RawDataEvent` and `ProcessedDataEvent`.

Side-note 2: obviously, the event aggregator is not intended for non-broadcast messages. You can force it (either using distinct event types or, for example, by including a destination-id in the payload), but I'd prefer a messaging system that's designed for point-to-point messages.